# Window themes not getting applied

Tags: gnome, 14.04, themes, metacity, gnome-tweak-tool

I downloaded `Tweak Tool` changing window theme doesn't change anything but changing from `Appearance` changes.

Why is it so?

- Has the default theme directory changed from `/usr/share/themes`?
- Tweak tool doesnt work for Unity?
- How to install new (metacity,gtk3) themes downloaded from gnome-look.org ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 14.04 Ubuntu stopped using metacity to draown the windows, and now it's integrated with the gtk css code (located in [theme]/gtk-3.0). You have to find a theme that supports Unity 14.04 windows.

Here's a sample from Zukiwi theme

```
UnityDecoration.top {
    border: 0px solid shade (@theme_bg_color, 0.5);
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0; /* Corner radius, only the top ones should be */
    padding: 1px 8px 0 8px; /* This padding will be applied to the content of the top layout */
    background-color: @theme_bg_color; /* Decoration background */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
        @wm_bg_a,
        @wm_bg_b);
    color: @theme_fg_color; /* The foreground color will be used to paint the text */
    text-shadow: 0 1px @wm_title_shadow;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px alpha(@theme_base_color, 0.6);
}
```

You can paste this in the gtk.css file of your theme and tweak as you like.

Comment: Can you elaborate your first line? themes integrated means? which contains metacity+gtk? I didnt get your first line

Comment: Before 14.04, unity used metacity themes to drawn the windows, which is located in theme/metacity-1. Now it's integrated with the gtk3 css code, which is located in theme/gtk-3.0

Comment: is it clear now?

Comment: I just downloaded Gtk 3.0 theme, I pasted in /usr/share/themes still Ubuntu cant recognize? What should I do to make it work.

Comment: I did not find any themes for 14.04 but I found something good gtk-theme-config :)

Comment: You can try Zukitwo and Zukini. So far they're the only ones I've seen 100% ported to 14.04